# Report "Cannot Open Connection" on other machines

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports

My application generates a report, which pulls data from a mySQL server. It works fine on my machine but other machines could not find the runtime. After installing it, I get an error that it cannot open the connection on that other machine.

Do I have to install the ODBC runtime and add the connection to ODBC on every single machine I want to install my application on? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OBDC connection then:

```
1. You need to set up the connection again in other machine by using administrative tools, in addition too.. install odbc driver also.
2. Connection name can be the same with your local machine so that you don't need to update the connection name on your crystal report.
3. if you are using a hard code connection to your crystal report upon logging in then you need to open your project of course to update the connection.
```

Good luck.